# Optional middle parameter in MVC4 Route

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to create a controller action that receives several parameters for filtering a scope and then the final parameter is a required paging parameter for paging the results.

```
//Example Action
public ActionResult Details(string time, string regionscope, string localscope = null, int page = 1) {

}

//RouteConfig.cs
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "LocationWithLocalScopeRoute",
    url: "/Details/{time}/{regionscope}/{localscope}/{page}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Location",
        action = "Details",
        localscope = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

Is there anyway I can exclude the `localscope` parameter but still have the `page` parameter be interpreted as the page number by the controller (while still maintaining pretty URLs)?

```
// Test URLs
/Details/May-17/Mid/1
/Details/May-17/Mid/Bumville/1
```

I know I could add a route before the existing route:

```
//RouteConfig.cs
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "LocationWithNoLocalScopeRoute",
    url: "/Details/{time}/{regionscope}/{page}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Location",
        action = "Details"
    }
);
```

I also realize I could put `page` before any of the other parameters.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "LocationWithLocalScopeRoute",
    url: "/Details/{page}/{time}/{regionscope}/{localscope}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Location",
        action = "Details",
        localscope = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

Was just wondering if there was a way to make it work all in one route definition while still having the Test URLs work.

Comment: Short answer is no (unless you create multiple routes). Only the last parameter can be optional.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Of the alternate options I added, which would you recommend? Or if you have another way, I'd be happy to read it.

Comment: Personally I would go with your 1st option, only because I think it makes more sense as a url to have the page number last

Comment: @StephenMuecke, do you mind putting some of that into an answer so I can check it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not without creating another specific route or making `localscope` the last parameter.

When using routing, only the last parameter can be marked as `UrlParameter.Optional`. If more that one is optional, then the routing engine has no way to know which route segment applies to which method parameter.

In your case when the url is `../Details/May-17/Mid/1`, is the last segment with the value of `1` the value for `localscope` or the value for `page`? There is no way to determine that, so if you were to generate the url using `@Url.Action()` (or one of the other methods that generate url's), then the url will be generated with query string values, not route values.